# Jquery find all form elements with a certain data- and then find the matching label and change it's contents

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm particularly lazy and I'm trying to have jQuery add the little asterix to the label of all required form fields.

MVC adds "data-val-required" attributes to all required form fields. I know I can find all the matching elements using $("form").find("[data-val-required]") but then I'm unclear how to loop through that collection and append the * to label with matching name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$("[data-val-required]").each(function() { $("label[for=" + this.id + "]").addClass("required") });
```

css:

```
 label.required::after{ content: " *" }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rxw8k/3/

Comment: Well that's just beautiful. :3 `+1`

Comment: Thanks. I can see that $(this).prop is returning the proper value but or some reason the label's class is not changed.

Comment: I had a space where there should not have been. `label [for]` is looking for a child of label. It should be `label[for]`. I updated the answer. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxw8k/

Comment: Why retrieve the `id` with jQuery, when `this.id` is more concise and cheaper to run?